# Plotly DASH Redirect to external URL after running callback

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I have a button with a callback function which is supposed to call an API and then redirect to the URL provided by the API.
I already tried:

1. Putting a `html.Button` into `html.A` and then in button's callback setting `href` of the `html.A`
2. Having a `dcc.Location` in the main div of my screen and setting its href with `refresh=True` but they did not work.

Is there anyone who dealt with this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

1. You also need a dcc.Output component with the id of dcc.Location element.
2. Your callback should return a url as output.